# I need to COUNT the number of leads_id to the users ID from the same table

Tags: mysql

I need to COUNT the number of leads_id to the users ID from the same table. The result i am looking for is How many leads has in the leads table by id. If this makes sense;

This is what i have so far

```
SELECT id, COUNT(leads_id) FROM leads GROUP BY id

function getuserleads() {
$users_leads = "SELECT id, COUNT(email) FROM leads GROUP BY id";
    if ($leads_count = mysql_query($users_leads)) {
        if ($query_info = mysql_result($leads_count)) {
        return $query_info;
        }
    }
}
```

COUNT(leads_id) & COUNT(email) are bringing back the same results

"SELECT id, COUNT(email) FROM leads GROUP BY id";

RETURNS:-

id    leads

4  --  3

5  --  3

6  --  3

7  --  5

I want to echo the leads COUNT, not the ID

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kanop.jpg

If you look at this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgNcs.jpg

User ID # 5 (Billy) should have under the Leads Column the sum 3, as he as 3 leads asigned to hime

Comment: Can you share your table's structure? Also, what's wrong with the query you've tried? Why is the result not correct?

Comment: it's the COUNT sum that i want to echo, the result about gives all within the table, i want it to be:- How many users have how many leads

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UudxL.jpg

Comment: So, would this work?: `SELECT COUNT(leads_id) FROM leads GROUP BY id;` If you don't want the (user)`id` in the output, don't put it in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: And that column should really be `user_id` or something. naming a column `id` is not the best of practices.

Comment: So what is the remaining question?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, COUNT(leads_id) FROM leads GROUP BY id
```

Is fine.

And if you would use `JOIN` with the two tables then you can select the name also within the same query.

Comment: no, that will not get the result i am looking for, this will only echo out the actual email address. But thanks for your input

Comment: The ID is the user, the leads_id is the LEAD. so, for example id # 5 has 3 leads, and i want to echo the amount of leads for each user, in this example the sum would be 3

Comment: it's got me has this one ha ha :-)